# jquery validate - groups and their labels

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Good morning

I have been using the jquery validate function for a while and it's great. However, wondering if its possible to have the group error label only clear out once BOTH (or 3 or 4) elements in the group are correct. For example, if I have an empty first and last name in a group, the error goes away once I type in just the first name. I know I can disable the onfocusout function, but I would rather not. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does indeed look like a bug in jQuery validate (you could file a bug [here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues)). To get around it you could define a very specific custom rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod("name", function(value, element) {
    return $("#firstname").val() !== '' && $("#lastname").val() !== '';
}, "Name is required");
```

And still use the `groups` functionality:

```
$("form").validate({
    groups: {
        name: "firstname lastname"
    },
    firstname: "name",
    lastname: "name",
    errorPlacement: function(error, $element) {
        var name = $element.attr("name");
        if (name === "firstname" || name === "lastname") {
            error.insertAfter("#name");
        } else {
            error.insertAfter($element);
        }
    }
});
```

The custom rule feels unmaintainable and hacky, since if your field `id`s change, your validation will break. However, it does get rid of the problem.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rqbws/

Comment: hm, i see. however how would this work when i have several rules that apply to each field (regex, custom, etc) in a group?

Comment: @Ortal: You're right, it isn't a robust solution. I'll try to come up with something better. It's unfortunate that jQuery validate doesn't handle this automatically.