# How to check if one list menu have a value greater than zero in jquery form validation?

Tags: jquery-validate

I have more select menus, named menu1, menu2, menu3 etc...

All of them have values from 0 to 10. By default all are on 0.

How do I check with jquery validation plugin that at least one of the menus have a greater than zero value? Because each has a different name (I can give same class, but I do not see how this helps in validation plugin, because I can validate rules against form names not classes).

Comment: What is wrong with the answer provided to you two days ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a custom rule.

I have adapted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454368/678338) and added a custom rule called **mulitselect**.   This adds an error to the first dropdown list if none have a value > 0.  [Check the demo on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yWN4e/)

**note1** This currently is applied to every select list in the form, change the selector to limit it to certain select lists by class or otherwise.

**note2** I added the onclick function after an invalid form has been submitted as adding it in the options resulted in validation that was a little too 'eager'.

js is as follows

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("multiselect", function (value, element) {
        var countValid = $('select').filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() > 0;
        }).length;
        if (countValid === 0 && $('select:first')[0] === element) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }, "please select at least one of the menus");

    $('select').addClass("multiselect");
    $('form').bind("invalid-form", function () {
        $('form').validate().settings.onclick = function () { $("form").valid() };
    }).validate({
        debug: true
    });

});
```